# Windows taskbar flashing orange

Tags: windows, regedit

### **Problem**

I dont like it, when the windows taskbar is flashing orange, for example Microsoft Teams if there is a new notification. It disturbs my workflow and breaks my concentration.

### **Steps done**

I tried to remove the orange flashing with the following:

- Windows + R -> Regedit
- Go to Directory Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop
- Change ForegroundFlashCount and ForegroundLockTimeout to value 0
- Restart Computer

[image: ForegroundFlashCount and ForegroundLockTimeout in Regedit]

### Wished Behavior

It would be best if the symbol did not blink at all, but it would also be nice if it only blinked once when there was a new notification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I remember correctly, `0` is invalid and Windows will ignore it, so just use `1`. And don't zero the foreground lock, or any program would steal your window focus, thus indeed break your workflow.

Comment: This solution doesn't appear to work anymore. Any other ideas?

Comment: @LShaver What means 'doesn't work'? What's have you done, what's expected, and what's happeded, please?

Comment: I have the problem described in the question, and implemented the solution provided by your answer, yet the problem remains.

Comment: @LShaver Oh, you want to cancel the flashing? My solution just get it flash once.

Answer (score 1):

The following solution isn't making any permanent changes, only
in-memory redirecting/patching some function calls in explorer.exe. If you execute it manually to test out, then log out and back in, and then everything should be reset (or simply restart explorer.exe in Task Manager). I use it myself on Windows 10. However I do have to mention in case if you want to test it first, that it only works if it's executed before any taskbar flashing occurs. So keep that in mind.

Install AutoHotkey v1.1 and download DisableFlashingTaskbarButtons.ahk from the following GitHub repository: https://github.com/Ciantic/DisableFlashingTaskbarButtons

Then make a shortcut of the AHK script and go to its properties window, and to the right of the target value add  `-NoMsgBox`. Then copy the shortcut, press WinKey+R, write `shell:startup` in the Run dialog box and press Enter. Finally paste the shortcut in the Startup folder which just opened and then you're done!

Comment: thanks, this is a game changer, i probably wouldnt have found the repo. such an annoying feature for those who use collapsed task bars like me